# Where did my Sharepoint Sites go? Sites disappear from main menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, menu-item

We have 21 sites of which 7 appear on the main menu as frequently visited. Our site called "Billing" fell off the main menu of frequently visited sites. The "Billing" site still exists. Documents from "Billing" appear if I do a search. "Billing" is still in the administrator list of active sites. If I manually go to a main menu site and change the link by hand to "Billing", I will arrive at a functioning "Billing" site.

Even though "Billing" is one of the most popular and commonly used sites, it doesn't appear when I click on Sharepoint. How can I get it back?

Comment: Could you please share where exactly you can't find your site link?

Answer (score 2):

The **Frequent sites** list on the SharePoint in Microsoft 365 start page is not modifiable by end users. You cannot "get it back" manually.

It is automatically generated by SharePoint itself to decide which sites to be shown based on user activities.
It does not necessarily promote the most recent sites on top, and would not show exactly the same to all users.

Quoting this [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/discover-content-with-the-sharepoint-start-page-6b85097a-87e0-4611-a29a-dfd49b1a1220) (Section "*What you'll see on the SharePoint in Microsoft 365 start page*"):

> If **12** or more sites are listed in this section, you'll see a **See all**
> link that, when clicked, will take you to a page that lists all of the
> SharePoint sites you visit frequently.

In addition, here is a UserVoice post you can follow or vote if you have the same request:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/19258060-customizing-the-sharepoint-home-page-showing-frequ